# Revert to multiple-display setting from OSX Mavericks to Lion

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, osx-spaces, osx-mavericks

I recently installed OSX Mavericks on my Lion Macbook Pro. I used to run a dual monitor system, and also used Spaces in conjunction with this. Essentially, this meant that with 2 Spaces open, I had 4 usable desktops, 2 on each monitor(plus the dashboard on my primary), and one swipe of four fingers would switch the Spaces on both monitors simultaneously.

However, when I upgraded to OSX Mavericks, the protocol changed. Now, each monitor has it's own set of Spaces, and it's own menu bar and dock too. To switch between Spaces, I have to swipe between them individually for every monitor. Whilst this may sound like a more efficient way to function, it's actually confusing and cumbersome.

So, is there any way to revert to the OSX Lion protocol of multiple displays and Spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think by disabling the 'separate spacies' functionality of Mavericks, you should be able to accomplish this:

Click on System Preferences > Mission Control > Un-tick “Displays have separate Spaces”. Once your restart your Mac, you will have just a single menu bar. Done.

[image]

Source: http://www.mactrast.com/2013/10/disable-second-menu-bar-os-x-mavericks/